# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sharedFunctions'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have a Python project in which I have the following folder structure:

```
> root
  > download_module
    > __init__.py
    > downloadProcess.py
    > sharedFunctions.py
    > someHelper.py
  > useSharedFunction.py
```

The `download_module/__init__.py` has the following code:

```
from .sharedFunctions import stringArgumentToDate
from .downloadProcess import downloadProcessMethod
```

The `sharedFunctions.py` file contains the following function:

```
def stringArgumentToDate(arg):
    dateformat = "%m/%d/%Y"
    date = None
    if arg.isnumeric():
        date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(arg))
    if date == None:
        date = datetime.strptime(arg, dateformat)
    return date
```

Then on the `useSharedFunction.py` I try to import the shared function and use it like this.

```
from download_module import stringArgumentToDate
from download_module import downloadProcessMethod

def main():
    arg = '03/14/2022'
    dateArg = stringArgumentToDate(arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I try to run this by using `python3 useSharedFunction.py` I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "useSharedFunction.py", line 4, in <module>
    from download_module import stringArgumentToDate
File "/Users/jacobo/Documents/project/download_module/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .download_module import downloadAndProcessMethod
File "/Users/jacobo/Documents/project/download_module/downloadProcess.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sharedFunctions import stringArgumentToDate, otherFunction
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sharedFunctions'
```

I do believe the error is in downloadProcess since at the beggining of the file we got this import:

```
from sharedFunctions import stringArgumentToDate, otherFunction
from someHelper import Helper
```

Which refers to sibling files.
However I'm unsure what will be a proper fix to allow to run the downloadProcess.py  main independently but also, being able to call it one of its method from a root or any other file out of the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this structure:

```
┬ module
|  ├ __init__.py
|  ├ importing_submodule.py
|  └ some_submodule.py
├ __main__.py
├ some_submodule.py
└ module_in_parent_dir.py
```

with content:

- `__main__.py`

  ```py
  import module
  ```
- `/module/__init__.py`

  ```py
  from . import importing_submodule
  ```
- `/module/importing_submodule.py`

  ```py
  from some_submodule import SomeClass
  ```
- `/module/some_submodule.py`

  ```py
  print("you imported from module")


  class SomeClass:
      pass
  ```
- `/some_submodule.py`

  ```py
  print("you imported from root")


  class SomeClass:
      pass
  ```
- `/module_in_parent_dir.py`

  ```py
  class SomeOtherClass:
      pass
  ```

### How sibling import works

(skip this section if you know already)

Now lets run `__main__.py` and it will say *"you imported from root"*.

But if we change code a bit..

- `/module/importing_submodule.py`

  ```py
  from module.some_submodule import SomeClass
  ```

It now says *"You imported from module"* as we wanted, probably with scary red line in IDE saying "Unresolved reference" if you didn't config working directory in IDE.

---

How this happen is simple: script root(Current working directory) is decided by main script(first script that's running), and python uses namespaces.

Python's import system uses 2 import method, and for convenience let's call it absolute import and relative import.

- Absolute import: Import from dir listed in `sys.path` and current working directory
- Relative import: Import relative to the very script that called import

And what decide the behavior is whether we use `.` at start of module name or not.

Since we imported by `from some_submodule` without preceeding dot, python take it as 'Absolute import'(the term we decided earlier).

And then when we also specified module name like `from module.some_submodule` python looks for *module* in path list or in current working directory.

Of course, this is never a good idea; script root can change via calls like `os.chdir()` then submodules inside module folder may get lost.

Therefore, the best practices for sibling import is using relative import inside module folder.

- `/module/importing_submodule.py`

  ```py
  from .some_submodule import SomeClass
  ```

---

### Making script that work in both way

To make submodule import it's siblings when running as main script, yet still work as submodule when imported by other script, then use `try - except` and look for `ImportError`.

For `importing_submodule.py` as an example:

- `/module/importing_submodule.py`

  ```py
  try:
      from .some_submodule import SomeClass
  except ImportError:
      # attempted relative import with no known parent package
      # because this is running as main script, there's no parent package.
      from some_submodule import SomeClass
  ```

Importing modules from parent directory is a bit more tricky.

Since submodule is now main script, relative import to parent level directory doesn't work.

So we need to add the parent directory to `sys.path`, when the script is running as main script.

- `/module/importing_submodule.py`

  ```py
  try:
      from .some_submodule import SomeClass
  except ImportError:
      # attempted relative import with no known parent package
      # because this is running as main script, there's no parent package.
      from some_submodule import SomeClass

      # now since we don't have parent package, we just append the path.
      from sys import path
      import pathlib
      path.append(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.as_posix())

      print("Importing module_in_parent_dir from sys.path")
  else:
      print("Importing module_in_parent_dir from working directory")

  # Now either case we have parent directory of `module_in_parent_dir`
  # in working dir or path, we can import it

  # might need to suppress false IDE warning this case.
  # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
  from module_in_parent_dir import SomeOtherClass
  ```

Output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" .../module/importing_module.py

you imported from module
Importing module_in_parent_dir from sys.path

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" .../__main__.py

you imported from module
Importing module_in_parent_dir from working directory

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks!